# How to get write permission on Android 7 SD-card using StorageVolume?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-sdcard, android-memory

Even after getting a permanent permission to write to the external storage I can't get write access to every folder of my sd-card. How to get those? For instance this app can do this, and I guess second permission dialog (under "Write permission on Android 7") is all about that. How to create that? [Article](http://www.lonelycatgames.com/wiki/xplore/write_in_android_5) Maybe, the solution is bound to the createAccessIntent method of StorageVolume class somehow...

Here is a code I'm currently using to get permanent permission:

```
RxPermissions.getInstance(getActivity())
                .request(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .subscribe(granted -> {
                    if (!granted) return;
                    showAlternativeDirectoryChooser(); // success
                }, throwable -> {
                });
```

Comment: Post the code that you tried.

Comment: @PrerakSola added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe, the solution is bound to the createAccessIntent method of StorageVolume class somehow

Correct.

> Here is a code I'm currently using to get permanent permission:

That has nothing to do with [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). That code is for [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: provide some code example or good link that contains usage of createAccessIntent, please

Comment: @M.Maximovich: Um, call `createAccessIntent()`, pass that `Intent` to `startActivityForResult()`. In `onActivityResult()`, you get the `Uri` pointing to your requested directory on the `StorageVolume`. From there, use standard Storage Access Framework stuff (e.g., `DocumentFile`), same as if you had used `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: I've done everything but the problem is that DocumentFile.canWrite() returns false, so I can't get the access. (but I have dialog, mentioned above, now). Maybe you can also tell me how to create some write free access folder there or something? Thanks

Comment: @M.Maximovich: If the `Uri` points to a directory/folder, I do not know if `canWrite()` works. That may only be for files. Try calling `createDirectory()` to create a subdirectory, or `createFile()` to create a file.

Comment: maybe I've missed the way to put the folder path to intent? It is not for createAccessIntent method, but maybe it can be put to the data with some key?

Comment: @M.Maximovich: `createAccessIntent()` takes one of the `Environment.DIRECTORY_*` constants. You cannot work with arbitrary directories.

Comment: Permission that I've got is granted for specific activity of for context? Because maybe the issue is that I'm trying to do those operations in another one. Because I can't even create a directory

Comment: @M.Maximovich: Yes. If you are passing the `Uri` to another component (activity, service), use `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` in the `Intent` for that other component. That holds true for any `content` `Uri` that you get from outside of your app; it's not unique to this storage volume stuff.

Comment: Just adding the flags did not solve the issue, but I have not passed the specific uri, shall I?

Comment: Btw, I've tried to create direcory in the same activity - no result.

Comment: @M.Maximovich: At this point, you are probably better served asking a fresh Stack Overflow question with a new [mcve] demonstrating what you are doing and what is not working.